# Hibernate updatable = false UUID field is updated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and am having trouble with the updatable=false property on the `@Column` annotation.

I have a base class for all of my `@Entity` objects with a UUID defined like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter @Setter @EqualsAndHashCode(of= {"uuid"})
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Persistable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

}
```

Note the `updatable = false` annotation.

To verify the UUID field is in fact NOT updatable, I have written this test:

```
@Test
public void testChangeUUID() {

    User user = userRepo.findOne(1L);

    assertNotNull(user);
    assertEquals(USER_UUID, user.getUuid().toString());

    final UUID newUuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    user.setUuid(newUuid);

    user = userRepo.save(user);

    assertEquals(newUuid, user.getUuid());

    User user2 = userRepo.findOne(1L);
    assertNotNull(user2);
    assertEquals("UUID should not have changed", USER_UUID, user2.getUuid().toString());
}
```

I was actually expecting an exception to be thrown on the call to `userRepo.save(user)`, but that doesn't happen. Instead, the final `assertEquals()` fails, which means the UUID was in fact updating.

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way to prevent UUIDs from being changed?

Comment: It isn't updating, your test is flawed. There will be no exception, the field will be silently ignored when saving/updating the object. Nothing has changed in the database. The problem with your test is that everything happens in a single transaction and thus single first level cache (i.e the `EntityManager`). The `user` and `user2` object are the same object (`user == user2` should return `true`). Your last assert is false as you have changed the in memory representation of the `User` object. Not the database one. You want to use a plain query to test this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/), the `updatable` property decided whether the column would be part of the update statement. It means that Hibernate ignores it when sending updates to the database. Thus, the in-memory state and the database state will differ.

To verify this, try clearing the session (evict) before calling `User user2 = userRepo.findOne(1L)`

Comment: I knew the first part, but didn't realize Hibernate was caching the object. I added `entityManager.clear();` before the `findOne()` in my test and now it passes accurately. Thanks for hinting the the right directly.

Comment: Strangely on the log there is another sql update that seems to put the original value back into updateable=false fields. Is this really necessary..

Comment: I had a similar problem recently and did not fancy clearing the session and doing the unnecessary finds in the repo - the solution was to keep the  @Column( updatable = false) and instead of using the repo .save method just create a native sql query to do the update of the field. The annotation only affects hibernate queries, there is nothing stopping you from writing a native script in your repo. Seemed to me to be the easier and more effective solution.

Answer (score 6):

While the original question has been answered already, I would like to highlight an important point **for people who are new with Hibernate** as it might help to avoid some confusion.

The [javadoc of Hibernate 5.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/)  of the @Column annotation, says for its optional element Updatable:

> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements **generated by the persistence provider**.

If you **issue an update statement with HQL or** using **CriteriaUpdate**, against a field that you have annotated  with `@Column(updatable = false)` , your update statement **will be executed** .

The `@Column(updatable = false)` works, when you are using either Hibernate’s `update` or JPA’s `merge` method.

No exception will be thrown (unlike for ex.: `@Column(nullable= false)` as it creates a constraint...), but the generated update statement will not include the marked field.

For further information, it is really a must to familiarise yourself with the JPA’s entity lifecycle states and the methods that manages them, as can be seen on the picture below.

As well as I highly recommend to read this [article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-save-merge-saveorupdate-whats-difference-one-use/) which explains this in details, *and is the source of the attached picture*.

[image: JPA’s entity lifecycle states]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as this one, where I wanted to use @Column(updatable = false) and then manually update the field in only a specific case.

As one of the solutions states before you can use the annotation and then try clearing the session before calling the userRepo.findOne(1L). That will as listed above work.

I didn't quite fancy the clearing and using more queries than necessary so my solution is - rewrite your save method to not use Hibernate at all, but rather a native sql script in your repo. The annotation only affects Hibernate, but has no effect on native scripts. Imo, a better way to do this.